# Top 5 LINQ query with group by using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, razor

I need top 5 LINQ query with group by using entity framework and below is sql query like that i need LINQ query.

```
select top 5 
    EventId,
    Datename(day, EventDate) as Day, 
    convert(varchar(3), EventDate, 100) as Month,  
    Datename(yy, EventDate) as year,
    Title, Description, ThumbImage  
from 
    EventGalleries 
group by 
    EventId, Title, EventDate, Description, ThumbImage 
order by 
    EventDate desc
```

This is my table structure in SQL Server:

[image]

This is my action method and I need a linq query to return list to my view:

```
public ActionResult Gellery()
{
        var list = db.EventGallerys.ToList();// i need linq query here in place of this list
        return View(list);
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public class EventGallery
{
    [Key]
    public int Sno {get;set;}
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ThumbImage { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }    
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string GalleryType { get; set; }  
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime GalleryCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
   //  Sno,ImageName,ThumbImage,Title,Description,EventDate,GalleryCreatedDate,EventId,GalleryType,Status

    public EventGallery()
    {
        GalleryCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Status = "Active";
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.EventGallerys
  .GroupBy(eg => new { eg.EventId, eg.Title, eg.EventDate, eg.Description, eg.ThumbImage })
  .OrderByDescending(eg => eg.Key.EventDate)
  .Take(5)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(eg => new {
      EventId = eg.Key.EventId,
      Day = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("D"), 
      Month = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("MMM"),  
      Year = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy"),
      Title = eg.Key.Title, 
      Description = eg.Key.Description,
      ThumbImage = eg.Key.ThumbImage 
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: The `GroupBy` is invalid/won't compile because you need to use the lambda parameter to access its properties `eg => new { eg.EventId, eg.Title ... }`. The `Select` won't work (assuming a SQL provider) because `ToString("specifier")` can't be converted by the provider to SQL. `eg.EventDate.Day` *may* work but if it doesn't you'd have to select some of the properties *first* and then process them locally in memory (adding in a `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` somewhere) after *only* selecting EventId, *EventDate*, Title, Description and ThumbImage

Comment: yeah i forgot to add eg.* but i guess it's obvious :) for the second part, asenumerable executes the query so the select is not executed in sql but in c#.

Comment: I missed the `AsEnumerable` in your code so you can ignore that comment. HOWEVER, its **not** obvious about the missing `eg.`: The OP asked *another question* using your code, because it wasn't compiling for him. One of the problems? Missing "eg.". You should fix your answer by editing in the missing parts. Also the `OrderByDescending` won't compile without making it `eg=>eg.Key.EventDate` nor will the `Select` since you're working with an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, Element>>`