# The name 'XYZ' does not exist while group by LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting below error

> The name 'XYZ' does not exist while group by LINQ Query

This is my action method which have tried.

```
public ActionResult Gellery()
    {
        var list = db.EventGallerys
            .GroupBy(eg => new { EventId, Title, EventDate, Description, ThumbImage })
            .OrderByDescending(eg => eg.EventDate)
            .Take(5)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(eg => new
            {
                EventId = eg.EventId,
                Day = eg.EventDate.ToString("D"),
                Month = eg.EventDate.ToString("MMM"),
                Year = eg.EventDate.ToString("yyyy"),
                Title = eg.Title,
                Description = eg.Description,
                ThumbImage = eg.ThumbImage
            }).ToList();

        return View(list);
     }
```

Below is my error showing in image format

[image]

Below is my requirement post yesterday but still not getting proper result.

[Top 5 LINQ query with group by using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676305/top-5-linq-query-with-group-by-using-entity-framework/51676716#51676716)

I also tried this query also but getting error.

```
  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

   var list = (from p in db.EventGallerys
                    group p by new { p.EventId, p.EventDate, p.Title, p.Description, p.ThumbImage } into r
                    select new
                    {
                        EventId = r.Key.EventId,
                        Day = r.Key.EventDate.Day,
                        Month = r.Key.EventDate.ToString("MMM"),
                        Year = r.Key.EventDate.Year,
                        Title = r.Key.Title,
                        Description = r.Key.Description,
                        ThumbImage = r.Key.ThumbImage,
                        EventDate = r.Key.EventDate
                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.EventDate).ToList().Take(5);


          return View(list);
```

Below is my return view design

```
@model List<IBAC.Models.EventGallery>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Gellery";
}
<br /><br /><br />
<h2>Gellery</h2>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <a href='@Url.Content("~/GalleryImages/" + item.ThumbImage)'>
      <img class='thumbnail' src='@Url.Content("~/GalleryImages/" + item.ThumbImage)' />
</a>

}
```

Comment: `ToString("MMM")` can not be translated to SQL that's why you are getting the error in second code. You can just do `Month = r.Key.EventDate.Month`

Comment: Please add your answer. @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linq `Group by` Anonymous object need to give a property name for the `group by` value and when you use linq `select` you need to use `key` to get the value.

```
var list = db.EventGallerys.GroupBy(eg => new {
                            EventId = eg.EventId,
                            Title = eg.Title,
                            EventDate = eg.EventDate,
                            Description = eg.Description,
                            ThumbImage = eg.ThumbImage })
                       .OrderByDescending(eg => eg.Key.EventDate)
                       .Take(5)
                       .Select(eg => new
                       {
                           EventId = eg.Key.EventId,
                           Day = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("D"),
                           Month = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("MMM"),
                           Year = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy"),
                           Title = eg.Key.Title,
                           Description = eg.Key.Description,
                           ThumbImage = eg.Key.ThumbImage
                       }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

You need to use a `viewModel` class to carry your data to `View`, becasue `EventGallery` this class is `DB` mapper model.

In this case you can try to use `EventGalleryViewModel` class be your razor `@model`

```
public class EventGalleryViewModel
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ThumbImage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Gellery()
{
    var list = db.EventGallerys.GroupBy(eg => new {
                            EventId = eg.EventId,
                            Title = eg.Title,
                            EventDate = eg.EventDate,
                            Description = eg.Description,
                            ThumbImage = eg.ThumbImage })
                       .OrderByDescending(eg => eg.Key.EventDate)
                       .Take(5)
                       .Select(eg => new EventGalleryViewModel()
                       {
                           EventId = eg.Key.EventId,
                           Day = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("D"),
                           Month = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("MMM"),
                           Year = eg.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy"),
                           Title = eg.Key.Title,
                           Description = eg.Key.Description,
                           ThumbImage = eg.Key.ThumbImage
                       }).ToList();

    return View(list);
 }
```

View

```
@model List<EventGalleryViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Gellery";
}
<br /><br /><br />
<h2>Gellery</h2>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <a href='@Url.Content("~/GalleryImages/" + item.ThumbImage)'>
      <img class='thumbnail' src='@Url.Content("~/GalleryImages/" + item.ThumbImage)' />
</a>

}
```

Comment: List is giving correct result when return getting this error :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`7[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IBAC.Models.EventGallery]'., but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IBAC.Models.EventGallery]'. and also check i have update my view in question .@D-Shih

Comment: Please check this url yesturday posted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676305/top-5-linq-query-with-group-by-using-entity-framework/51676716#51676716 . @D-Shih

Comment: @mazhar I edit my answer I would suggest you use `ViewModel` instead of  Anonymous object pass to `View`

Comment: What is the benefit of using `EventId = eg.EventId,` vs just `eg.EventId,`?

Comment: Actually I have alread model class na name: EventGallery as shown in above url and why again view model class just reading na. Your means i have to keep EventGallery class and i have to add one more EventGalleryViewmodel class na, because i am very to mvc5. @D-Shih

Comment: If you already have a model for view you can you the model create in linq instead of anonymous class @mazhar

Comment: Please explain i am new baby in mvc5 and if i will create one xyz class that is used in dbcontextclass and again i have to xyzViewModel class its mandtaory -  , now i am create class as you told EventGalleryViewModel. @D-Shih

Comment: After adding EventGalleryViewModel getting this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`7[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IBAC.Models.EventGalleryViewModel]'. . @D-Shih

Comment: Are you sure you `.Select(eg => new EventGalleryViewModel()` use `EventGalleryViewModel` in your linq from controller?

Answer (score 0):

Wath about :

```
db.EventGallerys .GroupBy(eg => new { EventId = eg.EventId, Title = eg.Title, EventDate = eg.EventDate, Description = eg.Description, ThumbImage = eg.ThumbImage });
```